# What is the best way to distribute my iOS app?

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store

I have one iOS app, I want to distribute that app only few members around 250. I don't want to place my app in App Store, because everyone can download my app. I have developer account, but I don't have enterprise account. I saw one more option custom B2B. Out of all which one is best for me. It's completely free app.

Comment: Use Testflight app

Comment: TestFlight to send private invitations.

Comment: can I know the expiry duration for app...

Comment: @ Phani Sai i want distribute for long time use...

Comment: Without purchasing an enterprise account, the only other longer term provisioning option would be Adhoc, this will require you to gather the UDIDs for all 250 of your members - also You can only register 100 iPhones for adhoc provisioning per account.

Comment: @  Wez is there any device limit, like same type  devices 100

Comment: Adhoc builds also expire, quickly

Comment: Your best option is to put the app on the appstore like everyone else, find a way to limit functionality to members only without making the app un-usable to the rest of the world otherwise it may not pass review.

Comment: @ Wez is there any device limitation for provisioning option

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Yes, you are only allowed 100 of each device. (Apple TV, Apple Watch, iPad, iPhone, iPod Touch)

Comment: @ Wez To get enterprise edition is it necessary DUNS number

Comment: Yes it is, and the annual fee is around ~£250 (can't remember exactly) - see here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Comment: @ Wez Thank u very much.....

Comment: If your organization has a DUNS number, get them to enroll in an Apple VPP account, and distribute your app to them through the B2B program.  That way there is no 100 device limit or short app expiration date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you already have paid Apple account, Probably what should be fit to what are you trying to achieve is the *[TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)*:

> TestFlight is an online service for over-the-air installation and
>   testing of mobile applications, currently owned by Apple Inc and only
>   offered to developers within the iOS Developer Program.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia Resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestFlight).</sub>

Although at some point you have to upload the archive to the itunes connect (not to the app store), you would be able to choose *specific* testers that would received an invitation to test your app.

Referring to number of testers limitations, note that there are two types of testers on TestFlight: *internal* and *external* testers; You can have:

- up to 25 internal testers per app.
- up to 10,000 external testers per app.

Furthermore, as an official reference (Apple) -which I recommend to check them for knowing limitations-:

- [Apple - TestFlight Beta Testing Tutorial Video](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/videos#testflight-beta-testing).
- [What's New in Testing Video Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/409/).

Also, There are many articles describing how to setup TestFlight, for instance you could check one of the following:

- [Steps to put your app on TestFlight](https://medium.com/@dmathewwws/steps-to-put-your-app-on-testflight-and-then-the-ios-app-store-10a7996411b1).
- [TestFlight Tutorial: iOS Beta Testing](https://www.raywenderlich.com/133121/testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing).

Comment: For test flight is there any device limitation

Comment: Like same type devices 100 only.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper I updated the answer.

Comment: For external testers if I use 250 has same model devices it's not a matter... Am i right...

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Yes, the device model is not a limitation.

Comment: Thank u ... Thank u ... very much.... @ Ahmad F

Comment: Glad to help  Btw, please don't forget to accept the most useful answer...

Comment: Testflight distributed apps expire after 30 or 90 days, so this method is only good for apps that can be updated and redistributed multiple times per year.

Comment: @hotpaw2 after the distributed build expired, you could simply upload another one, with an incremented build number.

Answer (score 2):

Developer Enterprise Program allows you distribute your in-house apps directly to users in your organization. If you’re distributing your app outside the store, you follow a slightly different process. You don’t have access to iTunes Connect and some app services.

Custom apps are distributed privately to authorized Volume Purchase Program for Business members that you identify in iTunes Connect. Customers sign in and purchase their apps (or get them free) on the Volume Purchase Program store.

Comment: is Volume Purchase Program  free account or paid account for me and  my users

Comment: It depends... Read the info here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/

Comment: My app is free app... is free account enough

Comment: In some countries "Yes", in some "No". Read the info in the link...

Comment: @ andy Thank u...

Answer (score 0):

You can make your app available to the selected members using "Test flight". But you still have to upload your app the app store but this app will be available to the members which you have given permission.

Comment: For test flight is it necessary to collect all devices id's.

Comment: In the iTunes console select my app, here you will see the test flight option. You can add testers by adding their mail id. Apple will send an invitation link on their email id.

Comment: No need to collect device ID's, only email ID's enough... Is it correct...

Comment: Yes email id is enough.

Comment: Thank u very much, is there any device limitation like same type of devices only 100 like this....

Comment: You can add upto 10000 external user for testing your application

Comment: If I use 250 devices are same type no problem... am i correct

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: @ Sushant Jugran Thank u... Thank u very much....

Comment: Testflight distributed apps expire after 30 or 90 days, so this method is only good for apps that can be updated and redistributed multiple times per year.

Comment: TestFlight is for beta testing purpose it is different than uploading your app to App Store for sale